# Error : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php

Soy nuevo en JavaScript y Php, estoy aprendiendo haciendo aplicaciones muy sencillas pero este error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

sigue apareciendo y no me deja avanzar con ninguna de ellas.

codigo:

```
fetch("http://localhost/Reposphp/fetch_api/post.php",{
        method: "POST",
        body: datos
    })
    .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(data)
    })
    // .catch(function(){
    // alert("No se pudo conectar al servidor");
    // });
```

otro ejemplo en el que me esta ocurriendo exactamente lo mismo es:

```
 var datos_enviar={nombre_empleado:nombre.value,correo_empleado:correo.value}
                
                fetch(url+"?insertar=1",{method:"POST", body:JSON.stringify(datos_enviar)})
                .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
                .then((datos_respuesta)=>{
                    this.Leer();
                })
                .catch(console.log("Error al insertar"));
```

Estoy dispuesto a leer los comentarios y aportar cualquier información mas para salir de este problema por fin.

Se supone que el servidor me debe dar una respuesta si todo va bien en el primer caso que es el mas sencillos la situacion es la siguiente:

```
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if($usuario === "" || $pass === ""){
    echo json_encode("LLenar todos los campos");
}
else{
    echo json_encode("Correcto <br>Usuario:"+$usuario+"<br>Password:"+$password);
}
```

Comment: El tema es ver qué datos de ofrece como resultado el servidor... por ejemplo, si comentas la línea `//.then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())` para que no se ejecute, ¿qué te da la consola? Y otra cosa... qué línea te da el error?

Comment: No pasa nada si comento la linea pero no hace lo que debe hacer, se supone que debo recibir una respuesta del servidor

Comment: Veamos... si abres el inspector del navegador > Red ----> Dinos qué respuesta ofrece el PHP. Ahí podrás ver lo que te viene de vuelta de la llamada. ¿Es un formato JSON? O al menos puedes poner el código del archivo de `http://localhost/Reposphp/fetch_api/post.php`?

Comment: No se como revisar lo que devuelve php, de todos modos lo voy a intentar

Comment: Y si pones  .then(respuesta=>alert(respuesta)) no funciona para ver que trae tu respuesta que según tu mensaje no es un json debes de tener algun error en el php

Comment: jorge el alert me envía: localhost dice object response entre corchetes

Comment: "Correcto <br>Usuario:"+$usuario+"<br>Password:"+$password en php se concatena con . no con +

Comment: Añade al php, al principio, `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` para indicar que devuelves un JSON. Y te recomendaría que uses una variable tipo `$respuesta=array();` después metas lo que quieras ahí (como por ejemplo `$respuesta->mensaje = "LLenar todos los campos"` o `$respuesta->mensaje = "Correcto <br>Usuario:".$usuario."<br>Password:".$password` y al final echo `json_encode($respuesta)`   --- Fíjate en que en PHP se concatena con **.** (punto) y no con **+**

Comment: tambien puedes usar .then(respuesta=>console.log(respuesta)) para ver en la consola que te trae la respuesta y si es un objeto ver que contiene

Comment: con console.log me devuelve lo siguiente:    Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost/Reposphp/fetch_api/post.php', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Comment: Cuando dejo el formulario vacío y le doy a enviar me regresa el mensaje de "llenar todos los campos" xd no entiendo de verdad, me envía un json con una cosa y la otra no, ya cambie los mas por los puntos.

Answer (score 2):

El error: *`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`* ocurre cuando desde PHP estás recibiendo un JSON no válido si has indicado en el `fetch` que la respuesta debe ser JSON.

Con cualquier salida no controlada que haya por pantalla desde el servidor tendrás este error (por ejemplo, un mensaje de error o advertencia, un bloque de texto, un BOM, un JSON no válido, como es tu caso, etc). Por eso, cuando esperas JSON en el cliente debes hilar fino, cuidando de emitir un JSON válido.

Dicho eso, lo cual espero que guardes en memoria y te evitará muchos dolores de cabeza en el futuro, paso a señalar que hay varias incoherencias en tu código. Vamos a enumararlas:

1. Cuando recoges los datos en el servidor, en este caso mediante la superglobal `$_POST`, debes usar las claves a la izquierda del objeto que has pasado desde el cliente. Significa que si declaraste esto en el cliente: `var datos_enviar={nombre_empleado:nombre.value,correo_empleado:correo.value}`, en el `$_POST` debes buscar `nombre_empleado` y `correo_empleado`. Asumo que estás pasando datos válidos. Te aconsejo que evites nombres de clave kilométricos, que producirán un código demasiado verboso.
2. Otro problema es que `fetch` espera un JSON en respuesta, pero desde PHP no estás mandando un JSON válido. Por lo general debes crear un array, si quieres devolverlo con `json_encode`, pero tú estás mandando cadenas simples.
3. Aparte de eso, en PHP para concatenar debes usar el punto `.`, no el signo de `+`, que es para operaciones aritméticas, aunque puedes prescindir de las concatenaciones si metes todo dentro de comillas dobles, de hecho, lo haremos así.
4. Por otro lado, llamas a la variable `$password` y luego evalúas una variable llamada `$pass` que no existe.
5. Finalmente, en el `$_POST`, como dije antes, las claves no coinciden con las que pusiste en el cliente. En ese mismo orden, te recomiendo que uses fusión de null (PHP 7+) o ternario (PHP 7-) para verificar el estado del POST, de este modo simplificarás.

Así debería funcionar:

```
/*
    Esto no tiene demasiado sentido, si
    vas a mandar un nombre y un correo
    llama a las variables $name y $email
    Lo dejo así para no modificar demasiado el código
    Estáte atento a la coherencia en tu código ...
    Lo importante aquí es que usamos las claves
    que usaste para pasar los datos, 
    que son nombre_empleado y correo_empleado
*/
$usuario =  $_POST['nombre_empleado'] ??  null;
$password = $_POST['correo_empleado'] ??  null;

/*
   Si estás en una versión de PHP inferior a 7
   cambia las líneas anteriores por:
   $usuario =  !empty($_POST['nombre_empleado']) ? $_POST['nombre_empleado'] : null;
   $password = !empty($_POST['correo_empleado']) ? $_POST['correo_empleado'] : null;
*/

/*
    Usaremos un ternario también aquí
    para definir el mensaje
*/
$msg=($usuario && $password) ? "Correcto <br>Usuario: $usuario <br>Password: $password" : "LLenar todos los campos";
/*
    Mandamos un array con una clave msg
    para que sea consumida en la respuesta de fetch
    Conviene poner una cabecera
*/
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode(array("msg"=>$msg));
```

Comment: Hola Cedano gracias por tu respuesta y tus recomendaciones lo siento por si mi pregunta no se entendió creo que deberé de formular la pregunta mejor mas preparado, pero es que esto es totalmente nuevo y estoy aprendiendo de forma totalmente autodidacta.

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que subí dos fetch de proyectos distintos. Así que lo mejor seria que yo eliminara esta pregunta trabajara los puntos que me has planteado y si algo  aun no funciona lo publicaré  de forma mas especifica con el ejemplo mas sencillo.

Comment: @DaniBN eres libre de hacer lo que quieras, ahora bien, si se ha hecho un esfuerzo por responder a tu pregunta, considero que no es buena idea eliminarla, creo que si aplicas todo lo dicho podrás llegar a la solución del problema. Por otra parte, si eliminas, la respuesta se perdería, el esfuerzo hecho también y el propósito del sitio es que pueda servir a futuros usuarios con problemas parecidos. De todos modos, como dije antes, la pregunta la has planteado tú y puedes decidir lo que hacer con toda libertad.